# rewrite to file server

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

There is a need to throw all the files sites (pictures, documents, etc.) on a separate file server (here dav server or Amazon c3), but the url in html not been change,  for example:
www.site.com/pictures/1.jpg in html looking into www.davserver/sitename/pictures/1.jpg/
I try use HttpModule with RewritePath, but get error that virtual path wrong.

```
 if (strCurrentUrl.Contains("/files/"))
   {
    app.Context.RewritePath(davserver +strCurrentUrl);
    }
```

Can I do it with iss+c#, or just ngix+rewrite?

Comment: Afaik [IIS UrlRewrite](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) should make this possible without any coding, just configuration.

Answer (score 0):

RewritePath is for ReWriting URL to inner of server, what you want to do is **Redirecting** not **ReWriting**,
Im prefer you do something like this:

```
string fullOrigionalpath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();  
if (fullOrigionalpath.Contains("file"))
{                    
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```